# I want to upload data to cloud or url that can save data

Tags: android, url, upload, cloud

I want to upload data to cloud or url that can save data. I created url and inside url I need to put my data. i.e www.google.com/something/DyDataNeedToPlaceHere/something.
 My app work cool and I can able to export my data as .csv file to my phone memory.

```
private static FileWriter saveToFile(final File file, final String contents) {FileWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new FileWriter(file);
        writer.append(contents);
        writer.flush();

    } catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (writer != null) {
                writer.close();
            }
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return writer;
}
```

Comment: So what is the issue?

Comment: I want to upload the file directly to the url. I need to put my data. i.e www.google.com/something/MyDataNeedToPlaceHere/something.  I don't want to store it to my phone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload File to server from android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37456918/how-to-upload-file-to-server-from-android)

Comment: Bro. check this link below. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42832910/i-want-to-upload-my-data-to-some-url-link-i-can-export-my-code-to-phone-memory)